# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: midi.inputs is not a function

Tags: javascript, midi, web-audio-api, web-midi

I am working on a project where im trying to get a midi controller to affect a three.js scene, but I keep getting the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: midi.inputs is not a function at
>   getInputs (baton.js:110).

```
var Baton = function() {

  var API = {};

  var input = null;
  var midi = null;
  var inputName = null;
  var connectCallback = null;

  API.callback = null;

  var inputs = null;
  var outputs = null;


  API.mappings = [];
  var mapCatch = false;
  var mappingOnDeck = {};

  API.connect = function(callback) {
    connectCallback = callback;
    navigator.requestMIDIAccess().then(success, failure);
  };

  API.inputs = function() {
    return inputs;
  };

  API.outputs = function() {
    return outputs;
  };

  var getInputs = function() {
    out = [];
    for (var i in midi.inputs()) {
      out.push( midi.inputs()[i].name );
    }
    inputs = out;
  };

  var getOutputs = function() {
    out = [];
    for (var i in midi.outputs()) {
      out.push( midi.outputs()[i].name );
    }
    outputs = out;
  };

}
```

Comment: your `.then(success, failure)` looks wrong. Only one value can be resolved/ rejected from promises. so it should be `navigator.requestMIDIAccess().then(success).catch(failure)`. What are these `success` and `failure` functions? where are they defined?

Comment: `MIDIAccess.inputs` is listed as a property, not a method, on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MIDIAccess). Try omitting `()` after `midi.inputs`

Comment: @MattAltepeter a promise's [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method can usually take two arguments. Having `success` and `failure` undefined would surely be a problem though

Comment: @Phil oops, my bad! Never seen the rejection handled that way

Comment: `midi` needs to be set from the success handler before use of course. I assume `success` is a placeholder for `(midiAccess) => (midi = midiAccess)` or similar function.